# How to display an activity or fragment on navigationView in Android?

Tags: android, drawerlayout, navigationview, side-menu

In Swift, we can use a Library called "SideMenu" to show a viewController on the SideMenu.

Now, I'm coding in Android. I want to display activity in the NavigationView we can only display a Menu or header.
I cannot show an activity or fragment on the NavigationView.

Can you help me or give me some advice about this problem?

[ANDROID STUDIO NAVIGATION VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNQi2.png)

[XCODE SWIFT SIDE MENU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRLyY.png)

Comment: did you mean adding a drawer layout for your application?

Comment: I have a DrawerLayout but I cannot add a fragment into it. I can only add a header with Menu. Otherwise in Swift, I can add a view directly.

Comment: okay, there are some different behaviour in both android and iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android app can display one activity at once (it's changed recently but in your scenario it's still true). In your case you should inflate View or Fragment. Just put your layout or fragment inside `NavigationView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">

        <TextView
            android:text="Custom View"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`NavigationView` extends FrameLayout so if you will inflate menu it will overlap. Because of that you may want to delete:

```
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I've already placed a Menu and Header. But what I need to display a View without "MenuItem" like presented in the picture of Swift Side Menu.

Comment: Than use code from answer and remove menu inflation - just remove: 
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"

Comment: Sorry, I've understand right now, it's working thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the android navigation component you can see the full detailed information to achieve this and replacing the fragments to corresponding to user clicks/choices [drawer layout with navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui)

if you aren't using the android navigation component and just using the drawer layout you can see this [drawer layout](https://www.journaldev.com/9958/android-navigation-drawer-example-tutorial)